# how to call function On text field value changed event using Javascript in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Please help me how can I call  function.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("input[title='IIN No']").change(function() { 
            alert($("input[title='IIN No']").val()) alert("Hi1"); 
            //TextChangeEvent(); 
            });
        }); 
    TextChangeEvent() {
        var IIN_value=$("input[title='IIN No']").val(); 
        alert(IIN_value);
        alert("Hi2"); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions that does not get down-voted and/or closed. You need to provide much more information. What is the expected output and what actually happens? Error messages, console messages, and so on. I do not know sharepoint, but in JavaScript you need a `function` keyword in front of a function name, i.e. `function TextChangeEvent() {`

Answer (score 1):

define it like this

```
function TextChangeEvent()
{
  var IIN_value=$("input[title='IIN No']").val();
  alert(IIN_value);
  alert("Hi2");
}
```

instead of

```
TextChangeEvent()
{
  var IIN_value=$("input[title='IIN No']").val();
  alert(IIN_value);
  alert("Hi2");
}
```